# What is the proper way to have my MonoMac app autostart?

Tags: macos, mono, xamarin, monomac, xamarin.mac

## The problem

I'm developing a Mac menu bar synchronization app with Xamarin Studio 5.0.1, .NET 4.5 on a Mac.  There is a preferences UI but other than configuration and the menubar item it is not UI centric (just like google drive, dropbox, backblaze, etc).  I need to automatically start (autostart) the app.  For comparison, Google Drive's sync app that runs in the menu bar describes their autostart option as "Start Google Drive automatically when you start your computer".  Whether it actually launches *with the computer* (as they state) or at login like I presumed, I cannot say.  Other than this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301016/mono-set-a-program-to-launch-at-startup-for-alternative-os) and this [incomplete answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17220540/how-to-make-xamarin-mac-app-open-at-login), I've not seen any MonoMac or Xamarin specific topic on to how to register an app for automatic startup.

## Ideas

The [following plist](https://github.com/wahlmanj/com.plex.pms.plist/blob/master/com.plex.pms.plist) appears that it was designed to configure an app for auto startup. But do I then need to call [launchd](http://launchd.info/) myself?  Will I have rights?

## What I want

How do I get my MonoMac app in this list like other apps do?
PS, I plan on releasing this via the App Store if deployment is part of the answer.
[image: Mac Accounts-LoginItems]